# Finding outliers in an array: how can I get my function to output the outliers using IQR method?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, outliers, iqr

I am trying to get my function to output the outlier in the array "data." I have created a graph to show the outlier, however I want my function to spit out the actual value also. Basically I want the value '220' to be outputted in my code. How can I do this? 
What am I doing wrong with my code? I think something is off with my distance

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import style
    style.use('ggplot')

    web_stats = {'Day': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Visitors': [43,53,34,45,64,34], 
    'Bounce_Rate': [65,72,62,64,54,220]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)
    data = np.array(df['Bounce_Rate'])

    def find_outlier(data, q1, q3):
          lower = q1 - 1.5 * (q3 - q1)
          upper = q3 + 1.5 * (q3 - q1)
          return data <= lower or data >= upper

    def find_indices(data):
           q1 = np.percentile(data, 25)
           q3 = np.percentile(data, 75)

           indices_of_outliers = []
           for ind, value in enumerate(data):
                if find_outlier(value, q1, q3):
                     indices_of_outliers.append(ind)
           return indices_of_outliers

    dist=data
    find_indices = find_indices(dist)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)               # 1x1 grid, first subplot
    ax.plot(dist, 'b-', label='distances')
    ax.plot(
         find_indices,
         data[find_indices],
         'ro',
         markersize = 7,
         label='outliers')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: have you tried "print dist[find_indices]" ?

Comment: Hey Ezer! Yes worked! Thank you, I was doing print(find_outliers())